# Am having too much fuel consumption on my Toyota Carina e 1994 model. Please what is the causes?

Tags: fuel-consumption

Having high fuel consumption on my Toyota Carina e 1994 model. Please what may be the causes?

Comment: Excessive use of the « loud » pedal...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What have you looked at? How many miles on the car? How long since you did a tune up? What do you consider "high fuel consumption"? Has something changed lately with how you drive, where you get your fuel, where you drive (city/highway), or how the car runs? Do you have a check engine light? If so, what do the codes read? There's a ton of reasons *why* you could be getting bad fuel mileage, but you don't give us anything to go on.

Comment: Add brakes binding, incorrect tire pressures, over-loaded...

Comment: @SolarMike, if you're trying to provide possible answers, please enter them in the "Your answer" text field below.

Comment: @BobCross just adding to the possibilities that, according to you Paul should have put in an answer...

Comment: @SolarMike, you are welcome to take Paul's comments and organize them into an answer.

Comment: @BobCross surely with the effort Paul put in to put them together  you should be asking him to do that - why direct at me and not Paul... Seems an interesting question for you to justify...

Comment: @SolarMike thanks. I already did in our direct chat line. We decided that you might like to answer the question. Things get tedious if the mods answer all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per the comments, there are many possible reasons for a change in fuel consumption.

I would suggest establishing a baseline by doing a thorough service : air filter, fuel filter, sparkplugs checked or replaced etc to make sure of the simple things. Also tire pressures, checking the brakes are functioning correctly ie not dragging or binding. Have the codes read if that system exists.

Once all of this has been done, evaluate the fuel consumption accurately - I use the « brim to brim » method as trying to base fuel consumption on 1/4 tank is not very accurate - then see how the fuel consumption compares over 2 or 3 tanks of fuel.

Hopefully it should be normal, unless your use is the cause - high loads, lots of stop / start etc.